# Baofeng UV5RA charger station error

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r, battery-charging

I recently bought 2 Baofeng UV5RAs from the same vendor. Neither of the charging stations work. They both flash green/red immediately upon plugging them in--before any battery is seated! When I seat the battery they continue to blink the error code. I have swapped A/C connectors and even tried different outlets. Same problem.

And no, the batteries do not charge despite the error codes. They continue to discharge while in the cradle.

I am assuming defective charging stations -- but what are the odds both units would have the same defective parts? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I seem to recall that flashing red/green is normal behavior before the battery is inserted.  The problem most likely seems to be a lack of connection between the charging circuit and the battery.  You might investigate whether the battery is making good connection with the spring-loaded terminals.  Try cleaning the terminals with a pencil eraser.  Of course the root of the problem could be a lack of quality control at the factory.

Comment: Should the flashing stop (or turn to solid red) while the battery is inserted?

Comment: The battery has been inserted for ~60 mins, shows no change in charge (battery icon still empty). Doesn't seem like a working charger to me.

Comment: The light should stop flashing red/green when the battery is inserted.  (I think it goes red while charging, and then turns green when it's done, but I'm not sure.)  Does the light still flash red/green after insertion?  Can you tell if the charger terminals are touching the battery terminals?  Have you cleaned all the terminals?

Comment: Must be faulty stations -- I am returning the items per the seller.